# Disable an input with an If condition depend on a radio box ( IE Issue)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

`<fieldset class="form-horizontal radiogroup" style="margin-left:-10px">
    <label style="font-weight:normal" id="item4" class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left:0px;">1.a. Is the anticipated RLF lending area different from the geographic area described in ED-900, Section B.1?</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 checkboxcluster" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 15px" data-bind="css:lendingAreaDifferentCSS, attr: { title: lendingAreaDifferentToolTip1}">
        <div class="form-group-sm" data-bind="attr: { title: lendingAreaDifferentToolTip}">
            <label class="radio-label" for="lendingAreaDifferentYes" style="font-weight:normal;">
                <input name="" type="radio" value="Y: Yes" id="lendingAreaDifferentYes" data-bind="checked: lendingAreaDifferent" /> Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group-sm" data-bind="attr: {title: lendingAreaDifferentToolTip}">
            <label class="radio-label" for="lendingAreaDifferentNo" style="font-weight: normal;">
                <input name="" type="radio" id="lendingAreaDifferentNo" value="N: No" data-bind="checked: lendingAreaDifferent" /> No </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="form-horizontal radiogroup" style="margin-left: -15px" data-bind="enable: lendingAreaDifferent() == 'Y: Yes'">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-left:5px; margin-top: 20px">
            <label style=" width: 66%; font-weight:normal; margin-left: -15px" class="surveyquestion">1.b. If Yes, define the anticipated RLF lending area.</label>
            <br>
            <textarea style="width:90%; " id="lendingArea" maxlength="8000" data-bind="css: lendingAreaCSS , attr: { title: lendingAreaToolTip }, event: {focusout: checkLostFocus.bind($root, $data, 'lendingArea')}, value: lendingArea"></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>`

I want the text area landingArea to be disabled(inactive) in a default situation when there is no selection from the radio buttton above. It is also disabled when the selection is NO which means the value "N: No". The only time it is active and enabled when the selection from the radio buttons is YES which means the value "Y: Yes". I got this right in all the browsers but in IE it doesn't disabled it

Comment: I found the solution which is: 

I added to the function to javascript file: 

document.getElementById("lendingArea").disabled = true;


Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the solution which is: I added to the function to javascript file: document.getElementById("lendingArea").disabled = true; Thanks!

```
   lendingAreaDifferent.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        lendingAreaCSS('');

    //CountryName('');

    if (newValue != undefined) {
        //CountryName(newValue.Name);
        if (lendingAreaDifferent() == "Y: Yes") {

            lendingAreaCSS('requiredfield');



        } 
        if (lendingAreaDifferent() == "N: No") {

            lendingArea('');
            document.getElementById("lendingArea").disabled = true;



        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("lendingArea").disabled = false;
        }

        if (loading == false) {
            sendCommand('SAVE');
        }
    }

});
```